# What's the construction of "have each furnished by..."?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> I have heard some of my townsmen say, "I should like to have them order me out to help put down an insurrection of the slaves, or to march to Mexico, - see if I would go"; **these very men have each, directly by their allegiance, and *so*
>   indirectly, at least, by their money, furnished a substitute.**

1. What's the construction of this sentence? Does it use the phrase "furnish sb/sth with sth" or "furnish sth to"?
2. Does "so" here means "also? What's the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: "so" here means "therefore". The part after *so* is a conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand the verb-phrase, but in this specific context, the indirect object is not stated:

**to furnish [someone] with a substitute**

That is, to furnish [the government] with a substitute, which here means to send to the government someone else to fight in one's stead.

It was common practice for conscripts to pay a certain amount to avoid having to serve in the army themselves.

> ... these very men have each, directly by their allegiance, and so
>   indirectly, at least, by their money, furnished a substitute.

Let's reorder the clauses putting the adverbial phrases at the end:

These very men have each ... furnished a substitute directly by their allegiance and [*done the same*] indirectly by their money.

**so** can be expanded to *done the same*.

The phrase "their money" need not refer *literally* to paying such a fee to avoid conscription, but to taxes paid. The argument advanced in that paragraph of the essay (your excerpt contains only a few words of it) is that the man who refuses to serve in what he considers an unjust war must have "clean hands". The man who would refuse to serve must end all allegiance with those furthering the unjust cause. He cannot merely speak out against it and at the same time be  paying for it indirectly. His paying taxes to support an unjust war is *tantamount* to his sending a substitute.

P.S.  I tried to take a shortcut above when talking about the implicit recipient in the **furnish** "transaction" so to speak. Consider the following.

> We're having a party on Friday.
>   -- Great! I will furnish the beer.

In that case, **the beer** is what I will bring to the party. There is no mention of the beneficiary or recipient.

> The boosters club is going to paint the gym on Friday.  The school is going to furnish us with paint.

In that case, **paint** is what is being furnished (supplied), and  **us** is the recipient / beneficiary. Our status as beneficiary is expressed by the objective case, **us** not **we**.

In the Thoreau essay, those men, by paying money into the government's coffers, are *furnishing a substitute*.  There is no explicit mention of the recipient or beneficiary of the action. But it is understood from the tenor of the passage (and from the next paragraph) that the beneficiary is the government.

Comment: If "the indirect object is not stated", where is the preposition "with"?  Should"furnish [the government] with a substitute"  not be converted to "have [the government] furnished _with_ a substitute"?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I added some sentences, the townsmen seem to support the government(unjust), if they pledge allegiance to the government, why will they have a substitute not to go to war?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "have a substitute".

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by "see if I would go"?  That means, "I would not go".

Comment: 1. If "to furnish [the government] with a substitute" is right, why isn't the sentence written as "these very men have the government furnished _with_ a substitute directly by their allegiance"? I don't understand why it uses an "each" and don't have a "with";  2. Doesn't "directly by their allegiance" mean they support the injustice? It can be reasonable if it has nothing to do with the  previous sentence.

Comment: If I *have furnished a hat*, I myself have supplied [someone] with a hat.   In the Thoreau essay, those men, by their money, *have furnished  a substitute* which means that they have supplied [someone, or some entity] with a substitute. The "someone" is the government.

Comment: Consider: I have given him money.  I have supplied him with money. I have furnished him with money.  **him** is the entity which has been given something.  **money** is that which has been given, supplied, furnished.  The **substitute** is that which has been furnished **indirectly**  to the government by those men when they pay money into the government coffers.  Paying the money is the indirect equivalent to having other men fight on their behalf, so their protestations that they are against the unjust war are hollow.

Comment: They have **each** eaten an apple = **each** of them has eaten an apple.

Comment: I thought "each" was an object and it made the "have sb done" construction, I'm wrong. Is the sentence "I should like to...-see if I go" actually a conversation of two? A: I want to go. -B: I would not go.

Comment: Now I see how **each** caused confusion.

Comment: With respect to **see if**... Consider this miniature scenario: "That's right, you keep bullying my little brother like that. **See if** I stand by idly."  The words **see if** are a kind of threatened action. The **opposite** is threatened.  The meaning is "You can be sure, I will *not* stand by idly if you keep bullying my little brother."  In the essay, those men are saying, in effect: "I'd like to see the government try to send me to put down a slave insurrection...see if I would go" and their meaning is "If the government wanted to send me to do that,.I would defiantly refuse to go."

Comment: And the essay then goes on to say that such defiant words are empty if those men are paying taxes to the government to fund such military excursions. They are, in effect, each of them, furnishing a substitute (a man to fight in their stead) by paying those taxes.